# How to fix Adobe Premiere rendering glitch on M1 Mac

Tags: premiere, adobe, mac

Not sure what is going on, but glitch below is visible while editing and on exports. How can I fix this? Thanks for helping out!

[image: glitch]

Answer (score 2):

Converting source from VBR to CBR (matching 23.976 timeline) fixed issue.

```
ffmpeg -i "video.mp4" -r 24/1.001 "video_cbr.mp4"
```